# no matches for kind "IAMPolicy" in version "iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam, workload-identity

I want to access the service account using workload identity.

cat serviceaccount.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: serviceaccount_key@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: rao-sa
  namespace: test
```

my yaml file is policy.yaml

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: iampolicy-workload-identity-sample
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: serviceaccount_key@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  bindings:
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[test/rao-sa]
```

---

```
kubectl apply -f policy.yaml
error: unable to recognize "policy.yaml": no matches for kind "IAMPolicy" in version "iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1"
```

getting error on YAML file: no matches for kind "IAMPolicy" in version "iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1"

Comment: You might need to install [config connector first](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake when one did not install [config connector](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to), check step 7.

[How to enable?](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#setting_up_a_cluster)

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
    --update-addons ConfigConnector=ENABLED
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me after enabling this.

Comment: np @Gaurav Yadav

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources to IAM Policies and how to enable GKE Workload Identity

https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/the-infrastructure-triumvirate-continuous-service-and-infrastructure-delivery-with-argo-a33a3f76dc06
https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/iam/iampolicy
https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-gke-workload-identity

Also checking your policy.yaml file i found some misplaced items, please check if this works.

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: iampolicy-workload-identity-sample
  namespace: rao-sa
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: serviceaccount_key@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  bindings:
      members:
        - serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[test/rao-sa]
        role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).